# In vue cli project i am facing this error i am already work on several vue projects

Tags: vue.js

Error: No valid exports main found for 'C:\Users\Karim\Desktop\vue project 2020\image-new-project\node_modules\colorette
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewZRt.png

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

It seems your issue is related with path name.
Try to change folder name "vue project 2020" to "vue_project_2020".

The compiler can't resolve filename or extensions correctly if folder name contains space.
And usually, it's not good habit to include space and special characters in folder name.
In this case, you can use underbar "_"

Hope this helps you to understand

Comment: I tried this but still get this error but if i copy my 1 week ago project and run this no error occur for new project i get this error

Answer (score 0):

Update your node version. It worked for me.

On MacOs:

`brew upgrade node`

Comment: i have latest node installed v13.3.0 and thanks for you answer

Comment: but if i copy and paste my 1 week ago project it's working @Eric